# October CMS: Error Log in frontend

Tags: octobercms

when I'm updating my backend on the server, an error could occur. If so, an error log will be displayed. Is there a way to hide all the details for the whole world and just display something like: "Error occurred." for the admins?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have the debug mode enabled?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, October installs with debug mode switched off. You should enable it when in production. Open the PHP file `config/app.php` and update the debug value to `false`.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Debug Mode
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
| stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
| application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
|
| You can create a CMS page with route "/error" to set the contents
| of this page. Otherwise a default error page is shown.
|
*/

'debug' => true,
```

This will convert errors to be generic and is recommended by the documentation.

http://octobercms.com/docs/setup/configuration#debug-mode

> **Important**: Always set the `app.debug` setting to `false` for production environments.

Comment: 2nd sentence: You should **disable** it when in production. Or you should **enable** it when in development.